# How to Resolve MySQL Service Start Error in Laragon?

Tags: mysql, laragon

I can't get my laragon to work, I keep getting an error of " MySQL service can not start"

Failed to have laragon start, while runing a laravel project: Encounted an error every time i could start laragon, and Mysql stopped everytime,

Here is how i was able to fix it;
First I had Xampp Installed, So i thought changing the port number could fix it, but it failed, though in most cases, it can solve the error, then tried the second

1. Make sure there isn't any other server installed on your PC like XAMPP if you install multiple server in same PC it can cause port issues.
2. Make sure you installed laragon in your C drive or any other drive, it does not matter.
3. Reinstall: uninstall laragon app then go to the path where you installed the laragon in there you will find a laragon folder delete that folder and reinstall the app again.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? First at all, check which service using this port (`3306`, i guess) `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3306).OwningProcess` for Powershell (Windows)
`netstat -tulpn | grep :3306` Linux